# PostgreSQL: Querying the highest row in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables: `Customer`, `CustomerOrder`, and `OrderStatus`.

My database is filled with the following info:

**Customer**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob |
| 2 | James |

**CustomerOrder**

| id | customer | amount | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 83 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 432 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 58 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 33 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 | 10 | 1 |

**OrderStatus**

| id | description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | pending |
| 2 | completed |
| 3 | cancelled |

I need help writing a SQL query which shows the status of the latest order (highest order id), per customer. Running the query on the data would produce the following result:

| customer | latest_order_status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to use a join to connect the two tables however I cannot seem to get the latest order: 

```sql
SELECT Customer.id AS customer_id, CustomerOrder.status AS order_status
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN CustomerOrder ON Customer.id=CustomerOrder.customer
ORDER BY CustomerOrder.id
```

Comment: You should give a try to CTE (Common Table Expressions), they are very handy in this type of situations.  [Reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `max(CustomerOrder.Id)` in combination with `group by CustomerOrder.Customer` to get highest OrderId per Customer.

Comment: I ended up combining this with @federico-cristina's answer and got the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the windowing functions to order your orders by the customer in a descending order. The Row_number() function will assign the number 1 to the latest order.

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over ( partition by customer_id order by id desc)  as row_no FROM
```

to have only the latest data you can nest this query like so:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY id DESC) AS row_no
  FROM
    orders )
WHERE
  row_no = 1
```

Here some more reading: [postgreSQL row_number() function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/postgresql-row_number-function/)